# What happens if GPO (GPUpdate) is Interrupted

Tags: group-policy

I am writing a small script but it's important to handle the excpetion.

I am wondering what happens if I run GPUpdate command and it's interrupted.
For example, user closes CMD, closes their laptop lid, and etc.

Comment: Closing the command prompt window after GPUpdate has already been launched and loaded into memory, isn't going to terminate GPUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Policy updates set various configuration settings based on the configurations laid out in the policies.

If you interrupt the update process, then whatever settings had not been set yet, will simply remain unset, until the next time the policies are updated (either via GPUpdate, or automatically during the usual policy refresh interval on your domain).